# How do I display a DateTime field in a recordset in Classic ASP?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, asp-classic

I'm trying to display a recordset pulled from SQL Server using classic asp. I can display the regular data fine, however there is one field which is DateTime datatype in the database.

How do I `Response.Write` the date?

I've tried this

```
<%=objRS(FormatDateTime("startdate",vbshorttime))%>
```

But it throws the error:

> Description: Type mismatch: 'FormatDateTime'

What am I missing?

Comment: The recordset field `objRS("startdate")` if you want to use `FormatDateTime()` you can do something like `<%= FormatDateTime(objRS("startdate"), vbShortTime) %>`.

Comment: No, still geting the same error.

Script error detected at line 79.
Source line: Response.Write FormatDateTime(objRS("startdate"), vbShortTime)
Description: Type mismatch: 'FormatDateTime'

Comment: In which case the field isn’t a `Date`. Try `CDate(objRS("startdate"))` to see if it is a value that can be converted to a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly error that I missed. The data values were null so I added a condition to check for null values.